# Radius of convergence and bounded sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

If you have an analytic function $f(z)$ with radius of convergence $R$ when centered at $0$, I want to show that $|f_n|(R+e)^n$ is not a bounded sequence. The reasoning in a proof I'm reading is that if it were bounded, then $\sum_n |f_n|(R+e/2)^n$ would be a convergent series.

So, suppose $|f_n|(R+e)^n$ were bounded by $M$.  How would you use this to get the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we have

$$\lvert f_n\rvert (R+e)^n \leqslant M$$

for all $n$, then for all $z$ with $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant R + e/2$

$$\lvert f_n\rvert \lvert z\rvert^n \leqslant \left(\lvert f_n\rvert (R+e)^n\right) \cdot \left(\frac{\lvert z\rvert}{R+e}\right)^n \leqslant M\cdot q^n$$

with the quotient $q = \frac{R+e/2}{R+e} < 1.$

The comparison test (compare to a geometric series with quotient $q$) now says the series converges.